# Как организвать подписку в проекте на rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Есть сервис с настроенными devise и cancan. Нужно сделать премиум подписку с рядом преимуществ для юзера. Как обычно организовывают проверку, что подписка истекла/активна?
В голову приходит только вариант проверки всех юзеров по расписанию, что, как мне кажется сильно не корректно.

**Update**

Я имею ввиду не проверку есть или нет привелегии, а нужно ли списать средства со счета и продлить-отменить подписку.

Comment: Это т. н. "design decision". Уж решения об архитектуре собственного ПО вы должны принять сами, т. к. слишком многое нужно учесть. В частности, как часто вы планируете совершать означенную проерку.

Comment: делаете поле "время окончания подписки" (оно может понадобиться и для других мест, оно может быть вычисляемым в базе). Теперь, достаточно отсортировать по этому полю и пользователь с самой "короткой подпиской" будет первым (ну или последним :) ). Теперь, можно просто либо рассчитать, когда следующий раз проверять, либо просто по таймеру раз в час/сутки смотреть (так даже лучше). Имея отсортированный список, многие вопросы отпадут (например, не нужно просматривать всех).